# Android webview - loading a html page with .dae model

Tags: android, android-webview

I am trying to load a HTML page which will have an option to choose the .dae file(3d model) using file explorer and it should be loaded in webview. This is working fine in chrome browser but not in webview.

I have enabled the below settings.

```
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

I am able to choose the .dae file and after that nothing happens. Whereas it's loading the 3D model in chrome browser of the device.

Can someone help me on this? Do I need to enable any other settings? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Mobile webview is not the Movile browser, they have different render ability.
WebView is render ability cannot match the browser.

To sove this, use XWalkView of crosswalk to replace webview.
How to use crosswalk to render 3D models refer to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40858878/6521116).